# How can I play a portion of an audio file in a loop in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I've got pygame playing an audio file from disc. Eg, I can play a soundfile something like this:

```
mymixer = pygame.mixer
mymixer.init()
mysound = mymixer.Sound(path_to_file)
mysound.play(-1)
```

But I want to be able to say something along the lines of:

```
mymixer = pygame.mixer
mymixer.init()
mysound = mymixer.Sound(pathtofile)
mysound.play(-1, start_offset_ms, end_offset_ms)
```

A little reading suggests that it might perhaps be done by importing the file as raw data and somehow trimming it, then using the resulting data to initialise the sound (?).

Alternatively there may already be wrappers to do this, or functions within pygame itself that I haven't discovered or understood how to use as yet.

Comment: Hi Mr. Andy Wilson. Did my answers help you by any chance? Or I miss-understood your question?

Comment: Just go to any audio trimmer website on the web, trim your audio from there, and then use it here

Comment: Hi Mo. Your answer was very useful in it's own way, and I will be using some ideas from it, but I need at this point to be able to play the sub-loop as a logically distinct source, ratehr than using timing / scheduling to achieve the effect. This would be simpler, and I need ot keep the logic simple as I am trying to create programmatic, rules-based music in real time (and hence will not know what sub-loops are required before run time), and being able to split the problem in two (define sound object as subset of sound file, then play that object in a loop) would make things easier to manage.

Answer (score 3):

to use the same functionality in pygame:

```
import pygame
import threading
import time


def play(sound, start, end):
    sound.set_pos(start)
    sound.play()
    time.sleep(end - start)     # in seconds
    sound.stop()
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    music = pygame.mixer_music
    sound = music.load("file directory/sound.mp3")
    sound_thread = threading.Thread(target=play, args=([sound, 1, 2]))
    sound_thread.start()
```

Note for the set_pos method:

For MOD files, it is the integer pattern number in the module. For OGG it the absolute position, in seconds, from the beginning of the sound.  For MP3 files, it is the relative position, in seconds, from the current position.

Comment: Pretty nice solution. Implementing it as a class, with methods such as ```forceStop``` would be a nice solution too.

Comment: This is a good answer @moe assai, perhaps you could add a non-threaded version too, as threading can be quite a complication for absolute beginner programmers (lots of whom are using pygame).

Comment: I used a threaded model to keep the game running as usual, and keep the back processing as usual. So that adding sound will be easier. But surely a no threaded model is a great representation for the work. But it will not function well in a full game.

Comment: @moeasal Threading is not necessary here as pygame does it automatically. It just adds complexity and is worse for performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can trim an object using only pygame:

```
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file='music.ogg')
raw_array = sound.get_raw()
raw_array = raw_array[100000:150000]
cut_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(buffer=raw_array)
cut_sound.play(-1)
```

This will create a new sound with the samples 100000 to 150000. The [`sound.get_raw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_raw) method will return a bytestring which you can index, copy or slice however you want.

Pygame also has a built-in module called [`pygame.sndarray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sndarray.html), which let you convert sound to numpy arrays for more performant and more fine-grained editing, as well as accessing samples directly instead of copying.

Comment: this is what I was looking for, useful in asynchronous scenarios where time.sleep would block execution.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe the Pygame library has this feature built in. But you have options:

1) If using Linux, you can try out [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Main-options).

```
ffmpeg -i youraudiofile.xxx --ss starttime -to endtime -c copy newfilename.xxx
```

2) Use a Python Audio/DSP library. Lets use [PyDub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown) as an example.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

audiofile=AudioSegment.from_file("path_to_your_file.xxx",format="xxx")
trimmed_file = audiofile[1000:2000]
```

3) Use a separate open software, such as [Audacity](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_editing_an_existing_file.html), to split the file.

Comment: Pygame does indeed have this functionality with `pygame.mixer.music.set_pos()`, but the suggestion of the AudioSegment / pydub module is worth a +1

Answer (score 0):

you can use the vlc model.

if you are a windows user, run this in your cmd to install the vlc model:

```
pip install python-vlc
```

this is how to initialize it:

```
import vlc
my_sound = vlc.MediaPlayer(path_to_file)
my_sound.play()
```

make a delay for as much as you need (like 2 sec), then stop it by running:

```
my_sound.stop()
```

if you want somrthing more complex and would never interrupt anything in your game, you can define this function using multi-threading and the vlc model:

```
import vlc
import threading
import time


def play(sound: vlc.MediaPlayer, start, end):
    sound.play()
    time.sleep(end - start)     # in seconds
    sound.stop()
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_sound = vlc.MediaPlayer(path_to_file)
    sound_thread = threading.Thread(target=play, args=([my_sound, 1, 2]))
    sound_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I need to be able to create the sub-loop of a soundfile dynamically, so can't resort to Audacity.

Using, as suggested above:

```
def play(sound, start, end):
    sound.set_pos(start)
    sound.play()
    time.sleep(end - start)     # in seconds
    sound.stop()
```

works but I would like to logically separate the creation of the sub-loop as a distinct sound object and the playing of it as a loop.
There are probably other answers, but the following combination of pygame and pydub works.

```
import pygame
from pydub import AudioSegment

pygame.init()
soundpath = '/path/to/sound/file/my_file.wav'
soundmixer = pygame.mixer
soundmixer.init()
newsound = AudioSegment.from_file(soundpath)
trimsound = newsound[1000:5000]
trimsoundraw = trimsound.raw_data
trimsound = soundmixer.Sound(trimsoundraw)
trimsound.play()
```

Arguably I should be doing all of this within pygame, and so I shall now spend some time trying to see if I can achieve that.